# limit of $ | x(t+1)-x(t) | $

Tags: real-analysis

I have a very basic question, x differentiable, then

$$ 0 = \lim_{t \to \infty} |x(t+1)-x(t)|= \lim_{t \to \infty} | x'(\gamma) | $$
via MVT ($\gamma \in [t,t+1]$), which is oviously not true, example $x(t)=e^t$. How can I explain this without an counterexample? My explaination is that $\gamma$ depends on t and t'=t+1?

Thank you.
Greetings.

Comment: Can you explain the $t \to \infty$ ?

Comment: There's no reason for $0=\lim_{t\to\infty}|x(t+1)-x(t)|$ to hold for general $x$

Comment: I thought $\lim_{t \to \infty } = |x(t+1)-x(t)| = | \lim_{t \to \infty } x(t+1) - \lim_{t \to \infty } x(t) |$ is not possible?

Comment: @user160069 it is possible only if the RHS is well defined, i.e., it is not an indeterminated form or some limit dont exists.

Comment: so if $\lim_{t \to \infty } x(t) = x^* \in \mathbb{R} $ , the statement is true?

Comment: You answered yourself? It is not clear what you are asking. Observe that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}|e^{x+1}-e^x|=\lim_{x\to\infty}|e^x|(e-1)= +\infty\neq 0$$